# What Bonus Feats and Permanent Stat Increases are available?

Tags: star-wars-kotor-2

Throughout the KOTOR games, there are a number of quests, and (especially companion) dialog conversations that yield special bonus feats, or permanent increases to the statistics of the PC (or an NPC companion). For example, repairing the various droids or breaking Hanharr's will in KOTOR 2 yields some free stats, or sparring with the handmaiden yielding the Battle Precognition feat that adds a Wisdom bonus to Defense.

Given the high importance of reaching various skill and stat break points (18 Con, multiples of 2 in other stats, crafting minimums for various skills), and the very high cost of raising stats above 14 at character creation, (and the opportunity cost of 'wasting' other feats or potential increases) it's helpful to know what the total bonuses one can expect over the course of a game to plan out a character. Thus the question: what is the complete list of these static bonuses (I.E. Not from equipment or buff or a class feature or a standard level up) that can be earned over the course of the game?

I'm playing with the TSLCRM Restored Content and M4-78 Restoration mods, if those have any bearing on the answer to this question.

I'm mainly interested in those bonuses gained by the Exile, but having bonuses for companions compiled (beyond the obvious "becoming a Jedi") would be nice too.

Comment: Have you read any of the Walkthroughs or guides present at [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/PC/920601-star-wars-knights-of-the-old-republic-ii-the-sith)? Most of them have the information you need.

Comment: I remember fully upgrading T3 gave some kind of bonus.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Yeah, I've looked them over. The problem is, none of them [*consolidate* the specific information I'm looking for along the axis I'd like to consolidate it.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/list-questions-for-the-old-republic-mmos-cw-closure-other/3722#3722) Furthermore, many of them are flat out incomplete or contradictory with each other (so much misinformation w/r/t Kreia's skill lesson for example), and that's before even getting into the fact that they're all out of date re: TSLRCM.

Comment: Suffice it to say: I'm not happy with the information that's out there, which is why I've asked here. It's incomplete, poorly organized, and buried in mountainous .txt files which are not conducive to search ability. I.E. Exactly the sort of resource that a question on Arqade is meant to complement and replace.

Comment: Remember though that the only two ways to answer this with a *full* list is to play the game (in all possible variants) or look into the game's files. KOTOR II is quite extensive, even more so (I suppose) with the *unofficial* Restoration Mod. Any answer that addresses these points will take some time to execute.

Answer (score 2):

copy pasta from google search:

•   Fully repairing T3 gives him +2 DEX, +1 CON, & +3 INT. It also gives the Exile +1 WIS & +10FP. The whole thing requires 14 INT, 20 Computer Use & 20 Repair, along with sufficiently high or low influence.

•   Fully exhausting Hanharrs' dialogue trees give him +2 STR, -2 INT & +2 CON, and gives the Exile +1 CON & +1 WIS. This requires sufficient influence with him (there might be some skill/attribute related dialogue checks involved, I'm not sure)

•   After fully exhausting Hanharrs' dialogue until you "break him" you can then talk to Kreia for the "Lesson of Strength." Accepting this lesson gives a further +2 STR & +1 CON to the Exile. I have also read that you can reject this lesson and get a different attribute bonus (I've read +2 WIS). This requires passing Wisdom dialogue checks with Kreia, though I'm also not sure how high Wisdom is needed.

•   Kreia gives you +6 FP and +1 Awareness for doing the first part of the "Lesson of Listening" and another +6 FP for continuing it. (Not sure if there's any requirements for these)

•   Kreia gives another +6 FP for completing the "Lesson of Skills." (I've read that being able to complete this and the listening lesson was an unintended bug and patched at some point, though that seems strange.)

•   HK-47 gives +1 Reflex Save, +1 WIS, +1 CON & +10 FP when you complete his first lesson in killing jedi, and the same bonus again for completing the second lesson. These require sufficiently high/low enough influence with HK to unlock.

•   I have also read you can get an attribute bonus for T3 and HK by bringing them in your party to GOTO's yacht, though I don't know the specifics of this.

•   Visas gives +10FP and Force Sight for following her dialogue paths and having sufficient influence with her.

•   Handmaiden adds your WIS bonus to your defence.

•   TSLRCM adds back in the option to spar with Visas under Kreia's supervision. Not sure on level/influence requirements or rewards from this.

•   Asking Atton about why he counts pazaak cards in his head after the listening lesson from Kreia gives you +1 Will saves

TSLRCM: Sparring with Visas gives you 1000 XP and Lightsaber Focus/Specialization if you don't have them.

Comment: If you are copying this from one or more sites, please use quote notation and attribute to the site from which you copied.

Comment: +1 for "copy pasta"

Comment: Pretty sure he found it [at Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kotor/comments/4uhy0w/spoilers_1_2_attribute_bonuses/).