# Maximize Defense in KotOR2

Tags: star-wars-kotor-2

The [Knights of the Old Republic series](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Category:Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic) calculates Defense slightly differently than [Neverwinter Nights calculates Armor Class (AC)](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Armor_class), with slight differences even between [KotOR](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic) and [Knights of the Old Republic II: The Sith Lords](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords).

How do I build a character to maximize his Defense in KotOR2?

I know that to increase Hit Points, Saving Throws, or Damage Reduction, or add Immunity to Critical Hits can also enhance survivability, but I want to know about maximal Defense. Also, I would prefer to avoid cheating (like duplicating the [*Name* Crystal](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Upgrade_items,_lightsaber#Name_Crystal) via [KSE](https://web.archive.org/web/20150320160757/http://starwarsknights.com/mtools/kse_333.zip)) and exploiting bugs like [the Lightsaber Crystal duplication glitch](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/920601-star-wars-knights-of-the-old-republic-ii-the-sith-lords/faqs/34337).

Answer (score 2):

At Level 30, I can reach a value of **71** in Defense.

### Character:

- Starting Attributes:

  - Strength (STR): 10

    - Leftover points go here
  - Dexterity (DEX): 16

    - Then increase every fourth level, yielding 7 increases at Level 30
  - Constitution (CON): 15

    - Why put any points into CON if we don't care about Hit Points? Implants in KotOR2 now depend on Constitution.
    - Why 15? Over the course of the game, [conversations with your companions can yield three<sup>3</sup> +1 bonuses to Constitution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/151144/4837).
  - Intelligence (INT): 8
  - Wisdom (WIS): 16

    - Stat increases [from companion conversation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/151144/4837) can provide +6 to Wisdom
  - Charisma (CHA): 8
- Light-Sided: Better [*Name* Crystal](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Upgrade_items,_lightsaber#Name_Crystal)

  - To gain all [bonuses from companion conversations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/151144/4837), you will have to make some Dark Side choices.
- Classes

  - [Jedi Sentinel](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Classes#Jedi_Sentinel): 15 Levels

    - [Jedi Guardian](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Classes#Jedi_Guardian) has the same Defense bonus, but Sentinel also give the immunities to Fear, Stun, and Paralysis, which fit better with a defensive character
  - [Jedi Weapon Master](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Prestige_classes#Jedi_Weapon_Master): 15 Levels

    - All of [the Prestige Classes](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Prestige_classes) have the same Defense bonuses
- Male: To gain [the Battle Precognition Power](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Force_powers#Battle_Precognition) from the Handmaiden, which adds your Wisdom Modifier to Defense.
- Feats

  - [Dueling](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Feats#Dueling)<sup>1</sup>
  - [Power Attack](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Feats#Power_Attack): No Defense penalties (and [decent Damage output](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/352740/4837), too)
  - [Finesse: Melee Weapons](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Feats#Finesse)

    - Does not affect Defense, but an obvious choice for a character like this. Note that Finesse for Melee Weapons implies Finesse for Lightsabers as well, though you can gain [Finesse: Lightsabers](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Feats#Finesse) from an in-game conversation midway through the game.
- Equipment

  - Implant: [Quickness D-Package](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Implants#Quickness_D-Package) (+4 DEX, +1 Defense<sup>2</sup>)
  - Head: [Circlet of Saresh](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Head#Circlet_of_Saresh) (+5 WIS)

    - The [Target Assessor](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Head#Target_Assessor) is a nice alternative for characters without [Battle Precognition](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Force_powers#Battle_Precognition) or for those who want to sacrifice a bit of Defense for a bit of Attack (+2 DEX, +2 Attack)
  - Hands: [Improved Automation Gloves](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Hands#Improved_Automation_Gloves) (+5 DEX)
  - Armband: [Vao Armband](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Arms#Vao_Armband) (+1 DEX)
  - Belt: [Aratech Echo Belt](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Belts#Aratech_Echo_Belt) (+4 DEX)
  - Robes: [Ossus Keeper Robe](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Robes#Ossus_Keeper_Robe) (+4 WIS, +1 Defense<sup>2</sup>)

    - For Robes, any Defense bonus counts toward the cap of 10<sup>2</sup>. For Armor, [the Defense bonus includes an Armor bonus](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic/Combat#Defense), which does not count toward the cap.
    - The [Matukai Adept Robe](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Robes#Matukai_Adept_Robe) (+2 DEX, +1 Defense) works well for characters without [Battle Precognition](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Force_powers#Battle_Precognition).
  - Lightsaber: Only a single Saber<sup>1</sup>, and only the [*Name* Crystal](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Upgrade_items,_lightsaber#Name_Crystal) matters, because the game only takes the highest of multiple modifiers for the same Attribute. (+5 DEX, +6 WIS)

    - Assume the [*Name* Crystal](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Upgrade_items,_lightsaber#Name_Crystal) at Level 30
    - Even though for playing purposes, this is probably not a realistic scenario because you can't upgrade the Crystal once you have found all of the Jedi.
    - Why not throw a [Fencing Emitter](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Upgrade_items,_lightsaber#Fencing_Emitter) (+2 Defense) in there anyway, to offset any Defense penalties<sup>2</sup>? In any case, I think it's the best emitter for offensive characters as well.
- Active Force Powers

  - [Master Valor](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Force_powers#Force_Valor) (+5 DEX, +5 WIS)
  - [Master Speed](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Force_powers#Burst_of_Speed) (+4 Defense)
  - [Force Armor](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Force_powers#Force_Aura) (+6 Defense)

### Calculation:

- Base: **10**
- Class: **14**

  - [Jedi Sentinel](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Classes#Jedi_Sentinel): 6
  - [Jedi Weapon Master](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Prestige_classes#Jedi_Weapon_Master): 8
- Dexterity: **18** (from the modifier for 47 DEX)

  - Base: 23 DEX

    - Start: 16
    - Level Stat increases: 7
  - [Quickness D-Package](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Implants#Quickness_D-Package): +4 DEX
  - [Improved Automation Gloves](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Hands#Improved_Automation_Gloves): +5 DEX
  - [Vao Armband](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Arms#Vao_Armband): +1 DEX
  - [Aratech Echo Belt](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Belts#Aratech_Echo_Belt): +4 DEX
  - [*Name* Crystal](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Upgrade_items,_lightsaber#Name_Crystal): +5 DEX
  - [Master Valor](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Force_powers#Force_Valor): +5 DEX
- Wisdom: **16** (from the modifier for 42 WIS)

  - Base: 22 WIS

    - Start: 16
    - [Companion conversation increases](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/151144/4837): 6
  - [Circlet of Saresh](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Head#Circlet_of_Saresh): +5 WIS
  - [Ossus Keeper Robe](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Robes#Ossus_Keeper_Robe): +4 WIS
  - [*Name* Crystal](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Upgrade_items,_lightsaber#Name_Crystal): +6 WIS
  - [Master Valor](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Force_powers#Force_Valor): +5 WIS
- Dueling: **3**
- Powers and Effects: **10**<sup>2</sup>

  - [Quickness D-Package](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Implants#Quickness_D-Package): +1 Defense
  - [Ossus Keeper Robe](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Robes#Ossus_Keeper_Robe): +1 Defense
  - Lightsaber ([Fencing Emitter](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Upgrade_items,_lightsaber#Fencing_Emitter)): +2 Defense
  - [Master Speed](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Force_powers#Burst_of_Speed): +4 Defense
  - [Force Armor](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Force_powers#Force_Aura): +6 Defense
  - Because this list totals 14, [the character can absorb -4 in Defense penalties before lowering his total Defense](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic/Combat#Feats_and_effects).

#### Notes:

<sup>1</sup>: Initially, you would assume Dueling would provide the highest bonus, since it grants +3 to Defense with Master Dueling. But then, you realize that Lightsaber upgrades can provide Defense bonuses, and that a [Fencing Emitter](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Upgrade_items,_lightsaber#Fencing_Emitter) and a [Lorridan Gemstone](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Upgrade_items,_lightsaber#Lorrdian_Gemstone) together will result in a Defense bonus of +4. But, then you realize the game caps Defense bonuses from Items and Effects at 10<sup>2</sup>, and you can reach that with Force Powers alone. And Lightsaber Crystals do not provide sufficient bonuses to Wisdom or Dexterity to overcome the +3 from Dueling. So, Dueling does indeed provide the highest ceiling for Defense.

<sup>2</sup>: I could only see the cap of 10 Defense from Items and Effects in-game, but it seemed to accord with the [rules from KotOR](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic/Combat#Feats_and_effects). However, any bonuses in excess of 10 can offset any penalties from Attack types like [Critical Strike (-5 to Defense)](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Feats#Critical_Strike) or detriments from Effects like [Slow](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords/Force_powers#Slow).

<sup>3</sup>: You can actually achieve four +1 CON bonuses, but instead of the fourth, you can gain a +2 WIS bonus instead, which has more value for the pure-Defense character.